# CSS hierarchy to allow a class to trigger styles to all siblings without that class

Tags: css, sass, logic

First - sorry for the title - if you have a better suggestion as to what it should be named then please let me know.

*I'm not sure if this is possible in the CSS hierarchy.*

I have multiple elements and each one can have a .show class added to it, to show the the content.

[image]

I'd like to set a rule, so if the .show class has been added - any of the same element without (.show) it are then hidden.

My current **not working** attempt is to use:

```
.team_item {
      display: grid;
     
      &.show {
        &:not(.show){
          display: none;
        }
}
```

So the logic would be:

```
element - should be visible
element + show class - element & inner content visible
element + show class - all elements without the show class should be hidden (display: none).
```

But I think I am trying to go back up the hierarchy in the CSS (scss).

Any help would be great.

Note: I'm fully aware that I can write JS to tackle this issue but was looking for a css (scss) solution.

Comment: well, it shouldnt work. Your rule applies to nested elements inside the elements that obtain .show. I believe you need to activate the rule :not(.show) with js. May be activating a mixin or a function could work.

Comment: @DanFriedman Yeah I had a feeling that might have been the case - I've stupidly realized after posting that I should be applying the rule to the parent element - Thanks for your reply - is it worth deleting this question? Its pretty specific and I don't think helpful if its expected behaviour (obviously if you want to post an answer then I wont).

Comment: No, wait, I will post an answer using a function.

Comment: What you are trying to do can not be achieved with CSS (or any preprocessor like SCSS or SASS). CSS can neither "go up the tree" nor can it reach preceding siblings. So even if one of your entries has `.show` you can only hide subsequent siblings, but not those that precede it.

Comment: The other elements have to be visible before adding .show class to a specific element?

Answer (score -1):

I believe it needs to be along those lines:

```
$team-item-display:'block'; 

.wrapper {

 @function hideElement() { 
     $team-item-display:'none';
     @return 0;
 }

  &.show{
       hideElement()
  }
  
  &:not(.show){
     display:$team-item-display;
  }
  
}
```

The direction of the solution is in calling a function that will set a different value of a variable that elements with no .show class use.

I havent tested the code. Hopefully it works.

Comment: That is not doing what you think it does. SCSS is compiled into plain CSS during the build step. Variables are resolved and replaced. There is no dynamic runtime behavior to it.